# Caching AVFrames using av_read_frame in a loop only get last couple of frames

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to process a video frame by frame using opengl.
I use ffmpeg to read frames from the video file.

Before I start processing the frames, I want read some frames and store them in the memory first.
So I try to using av_read_frame in a while loop, and copy frame data into a array,

But, when I try to display those frames, I find that I only get the last a couple of frames .
For example, If I want to cache 50 frames, but I can only get the last couple frames (frame  45 to frame 50).

Here's the code I'm using to caching the frames:

```
void cacheFrames()
{
    AVPacket tempPacket;
    av_init_packet(&tempPacket);

    int i = 0;
    avcodec_flush_buffers(formatContext->streams[streamIndex] ->codec);
    codecContext = formatContext->streams[streamIndex] ->codec;

    while (av_read_frame(formatContext, &tempPacket) >= 0 && i <NUM_FRAMES)
    {
        int finished = 0;
        if (tempPacket.stream_index == streamIndex)
        {
            avcodec_decode_video2(
                                  codecContext,
                                  frame,
                                  &finished,
                                  &tempPacket);
            if (finished)
            {
                memcpy(datas[i].datas, frame->data, sizeof(frame->data)); // copy the frame data into an array
                i++;
            }
        }

    }
    av_free_packet(&tempPacket);
}
```

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is defined as

```
 uint8_t* AVFrame::data[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS]
```

The operation

```
memcpy(datas[i].datas, frame->data, sizeof(frame->data)); // copy the frame data into an array
```

will copy `AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS` pointers into  datas[i].datas. This is incorrect because you only copy references to frame buffers you havent allocated yourself. Plus only the last frame(s) buffers are guaranteed to be available after `avcodec_decode_video2`.

To keep the data as long as you want to need to [clone](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#ga46d6d32f6482a3e9c19203db5877105b) the frame.

```
AVFrame* framearray[NUM_FRAMES];
...
if (finished)
{
     framearray[i] = av_frame_clone(frame);
     i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, you are right, I tried using av_frame_copy before, but it didn't work. av_frame_clone works like charm.

Comment: you're welcome. some ffmpeg functions are tricky and almost require you to read the source to understand what they are actually doing